# How to Display structure members in "Variables" window (MSVC 2019) [UPDATED]

Tags: debugging, visual-c++, include

I am working on a app built with MSVC 2019. In the past, I was able to view structure members in the "Variables" window while debugging (by clicking on the '+' sign). This week that stopped working: the Variables window just shows an address in hex).  I've not (knowingly) changed any build settings but the problem persists. No changes to source code.
**Any ideas about what I'm doing wrong?**

*I've tried:*

- Delete Debug subdir & rebuild all
- Checked: Settings->C/C->General->Debug Information Format: Using /Zi, but tried all other options.
- Checked: Settings->C/C++->Enable Browse Information: YES
- Checked: Varibles: Hexidecimal display NOT checked.

*Details:*
Include file dir specified by Settings->C/C++->Preprocessor->Additional include directories:
Compiled with MSVC v2019
Dell Optiplex Win10/64

**UPDATE 03/25/2021**

- So far, this problem only happens when I build an SSL/TLS app. I've tried several SSL packages with same result (GitHub OpenSSL, FireDaemon, Shining Light, etc.). I include ssl.h from each package.
- Members of structures defined *within* my app are shown correctly

Comment: What is the type of `method` and where is it declared?

Comment: I think I found the problem: Apparently the structures involved are "opaque" (binary blobs) in the SSL/TLS source code, so I guess I'm out of luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. According to
https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/OpenSSL_1.1.0_Changes, many data structures have been made 'opaque' in v1.1.0 and structure members are no longer accessible.
Great day for code purists but it makes debugging hard for the rest of us poor souls.
IMHO, It does not appear to be possible to work around this.

Answer (score 0):

You should uncheck `Hexadecimal Display` option under **Locals** Window.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for reply but it didn't work. "Hexadecimal Display" is NOT checked. See image in my updated question.

Comment: Sorry for that. Wow.. Since your MSVC 6.0 is too old that we did not support that and cannot test it on that. So please install the free VS2019 Community version. I test with that and can work well.

Comment: Perry: I rebuilt with MSVC 2019 with same results. I've updated my question accordingly.